# Jupyter notebook validation error after merging in git with nbdime

Tags: git, merge, jupyter-notebook

I'm merging Jupyter notebooks in git using nbdime version 3.1.1, and I see this:

[image]

I'm able to click 'OK' and complete the merge, but any time I open the notebook afterward, I still see this message. Is there a way to resolve the validation error after merging?

Comment: You have a conflict marker left in your file, which means you did not actually resolve the conflict before completing the merge. When there are conflicts during a merge, you have to resolve those conflicts, preferably in a text editor, and keep only the correct version - here you should have either `2 + 2`, which came from "local" or  `1 + 1`, which came from "remote", or both if that's the right thing to do, but you must remove the conflict markers, `git add` the file, and finish the merge before you can use the file.

Comment: In the image I haven't completed the merge yet, but when I do I still see the error (see the text under the image). I remove the conflict markers, run 'git add', and commit. But then I still get this error when I open the notebook, even without the conflict markers.

Comment: Then I would carefully examine what the merge did, and make sure it's still respecting the exact formatting rules that a Jupyter notebook requires. Or do the merge manually by inspecting the notebook in the two branches and creating the merged notebook yourself. Git merging is line based, but Jupyter notebooks have additional structure that Git does not actually understand.